# Query over multiple tables including SUM

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum

I am looking for the correct syntax

I can set up different queries but I am looking for one query

Tables:

```
T1
Country   Metal    Date       Pnum
Austria   Gold     20-Dec-18  P31182
Austria   Gold     20-Dec-18  P31181
Belgium   Grass    6-Dec-17   P30703
Italy     Gold     16-Nov-17  P30702
Zimbabwe  Copper   8-Jul-17   P29999

T2
Pnum    T  Week     Type  Color Descr               Status    Buy
P31182  2  2019-23  Apple Black Description one     Ready     200
P31181  1  2019-23  Apple Black Description two     Ready     150
P30703  2  2019-28  Apple Black Description four    Waiting   120

T3
Work    Hr    Pr    Pnum
AFNA    4     3.50  P31182
CONS    3     1.25  P31182
TREX    2.5   3.00  P31182
AFNA    3     3.50  P31181
CONS    3     1.25  P31181
TREX    2.5   3.00  P31181
AFNA    4     3.50  P30703
MEET    5     5.00  P30703
TREX    2.5   3.00  P30703

T4
Used      Pnum
3010.50   P31182
500.00    P31182
2254.47   P31181
555.55    P30703
155.25    P30703
```

Desired result: (minus the calculation in brackets, that's for clarity)

```
Country Date      Week    Type  Color   Metal Pnum    Descr            Status   Hr*T    Hr*T*Pr      Used*T      Buy*T      Work
Austria 20-Dec-18 2019-23 Apple Black   Gold  P31182  Description one  Ready    19      50.50        7021        400                
Austria                                                                         (4*2)   (4*2*3.50)   (3010.50*2) (200*2)    AFNA
Austria                                                                         (3*2)   (3*2*1.25)   (500*2)                CONS
Austria                                                                         (2.5*2) (2.5*2*3)                           TREX
Austria 20-Dec-18 2019-23 Apple Black   Gold  P31181  Description two  Ready    8.5     25.50        2254.47     150                
Austria                                                                         (2.5*1) (2.5*1*3.00) (2254.47*1) (150*1)    AFNA
Austria                                                                         (3*1)   (3*1*3.50)                          CONS
Austria                                                                         (2.5*1) (2.5*1*3.00)                        TREX
Belgium  6-Dec-17 2019-28 Apple Black   Grass P30703  Description four Waiting  23      93.00        1421.60     240                
Belgium                                                                         (4*2)   (4*2*3.50)   (555.55*2)  (120*2)    AFNA
Belgium                                                                         (5*2)   (5*2*5.00)   (155.25)               MEET
Belgium                                                                         (2.5*2) (2.5*2*3)                           TREX
```

If I do something like this I get wrong totals under the SUM columns

```
SELECT Country, Date, Week, Type, Color, Metal, Pnum, Desc, Status, SUM(Hr*T), SUM(Hr*T*Pr), (Used*T), (Buy*T), Work
FROM T2
INNER JOIN T1 table1 on table1.Pnum = table2.Pnum
INNER JOIN T3 table3 on table3.Pnum = table2.Pnum
INNER JOIN T4 table4 on table4.Pnum = table2.Pnum
GROUP BY Pnum
```

***EDIT***
Sorry, I forgot to include a Pnum in the first table. I will add it and will play around with the answers.
Table T1 is not very important. It only needs some info from there depending on the Pnum in T2

Comment: `GROUP BY Pnum` - which `Pnum`

Comment: For SQL Server your query is not syntactically correct.

Comment: T1 table does not have `Pnum` field

Comment: `INNER JOIN T1 table1 on table1.Pnum = table2.Pnum` your T1 table does not have any said column here.

Comment: How can your query even run?  It definitely won't run in SQL Server.

Comment: It doesn't run that's why I put the question. It's the idea for which I provide the example which I made up. I got multiple tables from where I need to extract data which includes SUM totals from different tables. I never done this before with more than 2 tables. Although I don't understand the answer from @APH completely at least it's something I can work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this (apologies for the vague references, but it seems that your original example is already somewhat simplified from reality):

```
; with CTE As 
     (Select Country, Date, Week, Pnum.... -- the rest of your columns here
     , sum(HR*T),... -- the rest of your aggregations here
     , '' as Work
     From T1
     Inner Join T2... -- the already working joins you have here
     Group by Country, Date, Week, Pnum... -- repeat the columns from the first line here

     union all

     Select distinct '', '', '', Pnum... --Add a '' here for each column that you want to be blank, otherwise pull the column name
     , Work -- retain this column
     From T3)

select * from CTE
order by Pnum, case when Work = '' then 1 else 2 end -- to sort the results the way you have them
```

Basically, you are creating your aggregate rows and your "work" rows separately, then combining them into one table and ordering the result to "group" them together.